# Why google full screen ads change my screen mode from landscape to portrait in iOS 8

Tags: ios, admob

my game is using landscape and portrait mode but when game is in landscape mode and new game start then admob full screen ads pop up and my screen orientation is change from landscape to portrait. Help me not change the screen orientation I am using IOS 8 iPhone 6

Comment: Strange, Are you using smart banners?

Comment: thanks kunalxigxag for atlas reading my question.
i am using full screen ads and i edit my question

Comment: That means interstitials. Have you tried turning the auto rotate off for your game? Or also, turn off auto-rotate in landscape and try. On what engine, are you building it?

Comment: i am using Xcode 6.1
yes i did auto rotate to no even then ads shown in potrait mode and other half screen will be blanked. 
admob while loading the ads get screen orientation and i check it when its  load its in landscape mode even then it showing in portrait mode